# How can I use dynamic manifest file in a PWA?

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

We have a SaaS platform and need to be able to load different manifest files depending on user settings. The user settings are fetched once the app is started and once this is done I want to load the correct manifest. However, this is not working. I have tried several different ways of doing this but I can't get the `beforeinstallprompt` event to fire.

If I load a manifest in my index.html and then don't change the manifest href it seems to work fine every time.

I have tried to leave the href empty on the manifest element in the index.html and then to update it later, but when I do this the `beforeinstallprompt` is not fired.

In my index.html:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="">
```

or

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
```

In my bootstrap js file to update the href to the manifest, once I know which manifest file to load:

```
var href = "https://xxx.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/sites/1/manifest2.json";
var manifestJson = {
  "name": "test in code",
  "short_name": "test in code",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "https://xxx.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/sites/0/icons/android-chrome-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "https://xxx.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/sites/0/icons/android-chrome-256x256.png",
      "sizes": "256x256",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "https://xxx.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/sites/0/icons/android-chrome-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "http://localhost:9000/home/",
  "display": "standalone",
  "background_color": "#2B3D4B",
  "theme_color": "#00afec",
  "prefer_related_applications": false
};
var stringManifest = JSON.stringify(manifestJson);
var blob = new Blob([stringManifest], {type: 'application/json'});
var manifestURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

// I have tried both ways of updating the manifest below

// $("head").find("link[rel='manifest']").attr("href", manifestURL);
$("head").find("link[rel='manifest']").attr("href", href);

window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', function(event) {
    console.log("poa: \nxxxxxxxxxx BEFOREINSTALLPROMPT xxxxxxxxxxx\n\n");
    $("body").addClass("hypo-install-prompt");

    // Save the event for later use (when the user clicks an install button)
    app.cache.beforeinstallprompt = event;
});

navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then(function(registrations) {
    console.log("Unregister ServiceWorker", registrations);
    for (var i = 0; i < registrations.length; i++) {
       var registration = registrations[i];
       registration.unregister();
    }
});

navigator.serviceWorker.register('/home/serviceWorker.js', { scope: '/home/' }).then(function(registration) {
   // Registration was successful
   console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
}, function(err) {
   console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
});
```

I know that this is a fairly common scenario and that many people have solved it but nothing worked for me so far. Anyone got a tip?

Comment: `I know that this is a fairly common scenario and that many people have solved it` - is it? can you show an example of a PWA that has solved this? (not the code, obviously, but the PWA you know has solved this "fairly common scenario")

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes I think it's "fairly" common since I found many posts/articles about this problem. However, none of them worked for me for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you fetch your user settings, you can dynamically write your `WebManifest` as a **Data URI**, so that the correct `WebManifest` is already being referenced as the page loads and doesn't need to be fetched separately:

```
<link rel="manifest" href='data:application/manifest+json,{"name": "test in code", "short_name": "test in code", "icons": [{"src": "https://xxx.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/sites/0/icons/android-chrome-192x192.png", "sizes": "192x192", "type": "image/png"}, {"src": "https://xxx.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/sites/0/icons/android-chrome-256x256.png", "sizes": "256x256", "type": "image/png"}, {"src": "https://xxx.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/sites/0/icons/android-chrome-512x512.png", "sizes": "512x512", "type": "image/png"}], "start_url": "http://localhost:9000/home/", "display": "standalone", "background_color": "#2B3D4B", "theme_color": "#00afec", "prefer_related_applications": false}' />
```

Comment: Hmm but this is exactly the problem I'm trying to get around. If I don't miss anything in your answer...? When the page load I don't have the user settings, i.e. I don't have the correct manifest file. Page loads -> app starts -> fetch user setting -> here I know which manifest to load.

Comment: Right. Fair enough. That was the section of the process I was uncertain about. If your set-up means that you can't retrieve user settings prior to the page loading using a server-side language (like PHP or Ruby) then I think your best alternative is to run a javascript in the `<head>` of the document which both retrieves the user settings _and_ then inserts the `<link rel="manifest" />` into the `<head>`, programmatically.

Comment: @Rounin I tried your solution (using my own icons of course)and get lots of errors in the chrome console. Is there another step missing, so that the data in the manifest href is recognized correctly?

Comment: Hi @Sofia. Can you ask a new question please, explaining what code you have put together and what errors the code has returned. Thank you. Once you've posted your new question, you can add a link to it in the comments here. Thanks.